# Form input to another page after payment

Tags: php, forms, http-post, checkout

I am working on a checkout process where a user must fill in some fields, then submits the form and redirects by a payment service to his bank and after that to a success page.

After the succes page, I want to sent the data of the filled in fields to an administrator, but I can't pass the date to this page.

So this is my process:

[image]

Normally I use the succes page as action for my form but because of the bank step I can't use this.

Can someone give me advice for where I need to search for to become closer to my solution. (database, session)?

Answer (score 1):

Normally when you submit information to a Payment Service Provider (PSP) you can send them an order ID, specific to that order. The PSP will then return this number, along with all the other information, back to you when the user returns to the success page.

You need to change your process slightly, so you submit your form to your website, and store the form data in the database, and then submit a second form to the PSP, or if you already have the information in the database then you can continue as you are, but only submit the order ID to the PSP.

Next, when the user returns to the success page the PSP should have returned the order ID along with all the other info. You'll have to check the PSP's specific documentation for what variable they use, but I've yet to come across one that doesn't have this facility. You then use this to load the rest of the form back from the database.